# Reverse a string. Not sure why this logic is wrong. C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in solving algorithmic questions. Until now, I have only self-taught coding. So, I am not sure about the proper conventions.

I was trying to solve a question to reverse a string.There is some problem with the code but I am not sure what it is after debugging step-by-step.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseString(string s) {
        int n = s.length();
        string reverse;
        for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            reverse[i] = s[n-1];
            n=n-1;
        }
        return reverse;
    }
};
```

Input: "Hello"
Output needed: "olleh"
My output: "olleh "  (extra space)

Input: A man, a plan, a canal: Panama
Output: No output

I searched online for solutions. There were related to pointers. It would be great if someone helped me understand why this logic doesn't work and why using pointers is a better idea.

ALREADY GIVEN. CANNOT CHANGE:

```
string stringToString(string input) {
    assert(input.length() >= 2);
    string result;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length() -1; i++) {
        char currentChar = input[i];
        if (input[i] == '\\') {
            char nextChar = input[i+1];
            switch (nextChar) {
                case '\"': result.push_back('\"'); break;
                case '/' : result.push_back('/'); break;
                case '\\': result.push_back('\\'); break;
                case 'b' : result.push_back('\b'); break;
                case 'f' : result.push_back('\f'); break;
                case 'r' : result.push_back('\r'); break;
                case 'n' : result.push_back('\n'); break;
                case 't' : result.push_back('\t'); break;
                default: break;
            }
            i++;
        } else {
          result.push_back(currentChar);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        string s = stringToString(line);

        string ret = Solution().reverseString(s);

        string out = (ret);
        cout << out << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use something like: `n=0; for (int i=s.length-1; i>0; i--) reverse[n] = s[i]; n++` Might be easier to read

Comment: Once you have this sorted out, take a look at `std::reverse`.

Comment: A string doesn’t expand when you assign to nonexistent elements. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: Fun fact: If you swap the characters you only have to go half-way.

Comment: @dustytrash It doesn't seem to work. Now the output is "olle�" (Question Mark and extra space)

Comment: It's simply because your code is wrong. `reverse` is initially empty, therefore in `reverse[i] = s[n-1];` (`i` being 0 on first iteration) you access `reverse` out of bounds which is undefined behaviour. Period. Compile in debug mode and then usually accessing a string out of bounds will output a diagnostic message during run time.

Comment: @caspian change this `string reverse;` to this `string reverse(n, ' ');` As jabberwocky said the problem with your code is that you have an empty string. The updated version creates a string of length `n` initially populated with spaces.

Comment: @caspian Don't add the answer to your question. You have accepted an answer, that's enough. If you want to answer you own question, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok, I will remove the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you create `reverse`, you have to pass the length of the string as an argument, else the created string will be of size 0. This could look like this:

```
string reverseString(string s) {
    int n = s.length();
    string reverse(n,'0');
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        reverse[i] = s[n-1];
        n=n-1;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `s` has been passed by reference. There is no need for `reverse`.

Comment: @user4581301: Don't you mean `s` has been passed by *value*?

Comment: I tried your code with  string reverse('0',n); But now the output shown is "olleh                        " (43 extra spaces)

Why are there extra spaces now?

Comment: @FredLarson  that's a roger. Ooops.

Comment: @user4581301: Good point, but I think then you need to make a backup of half the string, as you overwrite the first half before it is read.

Comment: @KaiGuther, just `std::swap` `i`-th and `n-1-i`-th elements.

Comment: @caspian I think we need more information here, maybe you can add the part of the program that prints the output to the question.

Comment: @KaiGuther this code is wrong, it should be  `string reverse(n, '0');` instead of `string reverse('0', n);`

Comment: Right, I somehow mixed up some stuff

Comment: @KaiGuther it could be simply `string reverse = s;` or better `string reverse(s);`

Answer (score 3):

Reversing a string is trivial. Just construct a new one from the reverse iterators:

```
std::string reverse_str(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
```

or

```
std::string reverse_str(s.crbegin(), s.crend());
```

Here's how I would write your function:

```
string reverseString(const string& s) {
    return {s.crbegin(), s.crend()};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read this, but I wanted to use some logic based algorithm since I clearly won't be able to use this in a coding interview.

Comment: @caspian: Why not? If I were conducting the interview, I'd rather see you using standard library features than rolling your own code for everything.

Comment: @caspian why wouldn't you be able to do that in an interview situation? It's the logical, straightforward way to do it. If I saw someone write out a manual algorithm to do it in an interview I'd be thinking "does this guy actually know C++?".

Comment: @JesperJuhl If the interviewer was trying to test my algorithmic knowledge. Won't this solution be a problem? Again, I haven't given any interviews before, but this is what I have heard. Yours is clearly a better way and I would prefer to use it.

Comment: @caspian If the interviewer wants you to demonstrate an algorithm they should *say so* (or the fault lies with the interviewer). If all they say is "how would you reverse a string in C++" I'd expect they want to see what you'd write in production code - which would (hopefully) be something like what I put in my answer.

Comment: Depends on the interviewer. I generally hire the candidate I have to teach less, so I expect library use and pose a problem where the candidate can either assemble a simple program of calls to existing functions or can roll their own. If the roll-their-own is interesting and shows insight, I might take a chance on them, but the library-user I can most likely put to use right away.

Comment: Of course, you might also  ask the interviewer _why_ they want to reverse a string in the first place.

Comment: I can remember reversing (only) 1 thing in embedded systems programming:  the clock chip's bcd output got connected to the data bus in reverse significance order.  I used a table lookup.  In other words, the software 'reverse' I coded was needed to undo an earlier (and someone else's) error.  In an interview ask "Why they might reverse a string?"  You might also ask, "Why did you not avoid it?"

Answer (score -2):

Try this out

```
class Solution {
public:
string reverseString(string s) {
    //cout<<"inside func";
    int n = s.length();
    cout<<n<<endl;
    char reverse[sizeof(char)*n];// reverse stores the reverse of original string  s
    int i= 0;
    for ( i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {

        reverse[i] = s[n-i-1];

    }

    return reverse;
  }
}

int main()
{
  string s,r;
  Solution sol;
  s= "hello";
  r= sol.reverseString(s);
  cout<<r<<endl;
  cout<<r.length()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

when i= 0,  n-i-1= n-1 which is the last element of the original string s. So the first element of the reverse string is the last element of s. Next i becomes i+1 i.e 1. This time second element of the reverse string is the last but one element in string s. This procedure is repeated till i < s.length(). The element to get copied is for index i= n-1 and n becomes n-(n-1)-1= 0, so the last element of reverse string is the first element of s. After this the loop exists. No additional extra characters are added.

Comment: Just posting code without an explanation of why it answers the question is not a useful/complete answer.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for pointing the mistake in the code. I have corrected it kindly have a look and let me know if anything more to be done.

Comment: The replacement uses a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and these are not legal in Standard C++. Some compilers allow them by extension, but using them greatly limits the number of compilers that can compile your answer. To differentiate this answer from the other posted answers, consider instead demonstrating reversing the string in place by swapping the first and last unswapped characters in `s`.